# Flex 4: Checkbox in Accordion header

Tags: apache-flex, checkbox, flex4, accordion, panels

I wanted to know if it is possible to add a checkbox in the accordion control.
The main idea is to have a list of selectable items (like selecting various items for checkout) and each of them should have an option to display additional information (the accordion panel).

So basically, 3 questions:

1. Can I have a checkbox in the accordion header?
2. Can I have all the panels closed from the start? So the user chooses which panel to open, and not start with one panel displayed.
3. Can I have multiple panels opened at the same time?

Some notes:
- I tried a header renderer option, but the checkbox was the same for all accordion headers, so it was useless.
- It would be great to avoid the use of libraries or external controls. I am aware of some of the limitations of Flex controls though.

Thanks for any help or information you can provide ! :)

Comment: It sounds like you'd be better off avoiding the accordion control and developing a renderer for a spark <code>List</code> control.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not dead set on using mx controls, I'd give the 4.6 list/item renderer skinning method a try.

I'd use the sparks list control and create a custom item render that's comprised of checkbox control, several nested group/border-container wrappers depending on your design/creative requirements and whatever as3 logic would be necessary to expand and contract the item renderer keyed off of the checkbox's click event or change events-- that's some of the beauty of skinning item renderers in flex 4, you can encapsulate all that dope-ass logic within renderer itself.

In any case, here's some links you might find helpful:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex4_skinning.html

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/06/21/creating-a-custom-halo-accordion-header-skin-in-flex-4/

http://saturnboy.com/2009/09/flex4-component-states-skin-states/

hope this helps!